# Scala / SBT Assembly Error: Could not create directory

Tags: scala, ubuntu

I get the following error when trying to execute the command `sbt/sbt assembly`:

> [error] Could not create directory
>   /home/user/Downloads/spark-1.6.0/external/mqtt/target/streams/test/$global/$global/discoveredMainClasses

I have no idea...

Comment: can you provide your sbt configuration

Comment: change permission by command:-  chmod 777 -R /project/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with something being out of date. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu with updates included and it worked this time. I probably could have also done this by checking each package manually, but this was easier.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions for creating.
if you run before this command with sudo and after that try it without sudo you will receive this message.